# How did Cobb find Saito in limbo?

Tags: inception

In Inception, I don't understand the ending where Cobb and Saito find themselves independently in limbo. Is it a coincidence that Cobb found Saito in limbo and that too just before the plane flight in the real-world arrives at its destination?

Comment: Hi Vivart.  Your question is a little ambiguous.  Are you asking whether it was a coincidence that he found Saiti *just* before the plane arrives?

Comment: @iandotkelly yeah i am asking the same thing. if this is a movie thing(hero found saito in limbo because we didn't have time and it was already 140 minute), it is ok. but i wanted to know if i am missing anything in logic?

Comment: @iandokelly Your edits of the questions made it more vague and the grammar isn't correct. Why did you edit my edit?

Comment: sorry @OghmaOsiris i have edited something but i have rolled back and in the result it becomes more vague.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris - my edit was submitted for approval at about the time your edit was made.  The grammer mistake was just that - a mistake - and then because I do not have enough reputation to directly make an edit it makes it harder to correct it.  IMHO it did not make it more vague.  Sorry, but this is a consequence of the approval system, I started editing the original post, not your edit.

Answer (score 9):

No coincidence; remember, the Realworld / Dreamworld time ratio keeps getting more and more severe as you go deeper and deeper.  The amount of time he had to search in Limbo was tremendous; it would equate to a very short time in RL, so it being completed before the plane landed is no real surprise.

Comment: my doubt is, cobb is in some limbo and saito is in some other limbo  and cobb just fall in empire of saito's limbo. It was just a coincidence or something else.

Comment: Limbo is multiple dream levels down from reality and each level they go takes them farther from outside stimulus; very little exists except what they create with their own minds.  Since Cobb and Fisher are still linked, however, it's not surprising that Cobb is able to find him; Fisher has shaped limbo by being there, and Cobb just entered -- the only stimuli currently present IS being generated by Fisher.  Think of Limbo as a huge mental vacuum.  If more than one person is there (and linked) it's inevitable that they will find each other; there's nothing else to find.

Answer (score 3):

Saito found Cobb. Or rather his men (projections) found Cobb. On the beach, where one arrive when entering limbo.

I think Cobb caught the kick out into the snow world and then re-entered limbo (possibly by dying in the exploding building). This explains why Cobb is young and Saito is old.

Saito had lived in limbo for a long time and monitored the beach, in case someone else came to limbo.